# How to center UITabButtonItem in the middle of the screen programatically?

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to move the DONE button in the middle.
[image]

Initially, it is located on the left side:

```
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.dismissKeyboard))

    toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Do you have an idea about how to move it to the middle of the screen programmatically? I tried to add flexible space but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must two create UIBarButtonItem with SystemItem: .flexibleSpace
and add to toolbar items first and last item :

```
toolBar.setItems([UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil), doneButton, UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)], animated: false)
```